# Can packed bubble while including Highcharts Gantt resource?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have added the src for Gantt Chart. However, in my code i also have other Charts displayed from the highcharts library. Since both sources cannot work together, i ended up only having the Gantt source `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>`
But now my "Packed Bubble" chart is not working anymore, since it is not included in this library.
Am i missing something? Is there a possibility to include `<script src="js/8.2.2/highcharts.js"></script>` as well?

Comment: Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using <> button in the editor and add all relevant code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add gantt as a Highcharts module. In the below example you can find a working packedbubble and gantt chart.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u4cpqx8e/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/getting-started-gantt